# Original command line as typed

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, arguments

I've run into a situation where it would be helpful to get the original command line as typed, rather than broken up into the args array. Simply joining the args into one string loses extra spaces between the arguments, and in this particular case they could be significant.

Is the original unparsed command line available anywhere?

Comment: why would spaces 'ever' be significant? They shouldn't be, for all the obvious reasons...(apart from file paths, but then you shouldn't really have double spaces in those either...)

Comment: @Mitch: If I do `cd c:\Program Files` it works. If I put an extra space between `Program` and `Files`, it doesn't work -- and I would expect it not to.

Comment: Because in this case one of the arguments is a search target that can be delimited by arbitrary nonalphameric characters, e.g. /what<sp><sp><sp>ever/, and the spaces are significant (the user is looking for a string with three spaces). The command line parser will break that up into two arguments unless it's delimited by quotes, which he can't use if the search target contains quotes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can do this through the [CommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.commandline.aspx) property of the `Environment` class.

```
Environment.CommandLine
```